# Do Java implementations exist without System.out? Is it possible?

Tags: java

So I'm pretty new to Java and this may be a question conceived due to some misconceptions, but I'm just curious: Do all "forms" (I guess different JREs? Or VMs?), for example, I've heard of Dalvik, of Java include an automatically imported System.out? What makes them different from the standard one i downloaded from Oracle to learn with? Inform me if I'm not understanding any concepts correctly, please.

Comment: If it doesn't contain standard Java library classes, how can it be called "Java"?

Comment: Maybe ask yourself - what is System.out?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels The syntax? Also, couldn't it just exclude System.out and leave other things in? Like I heard in Android System.out.println isnt used, so why not exclude it?

Comment: The syntax **is** Java, defines the Java language

Comment: In java System is in the `java.lang` package, this is included in all java classes, no special `import` is needed and therefore can not be `excluded` - is this what you are asking?

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels, that's what I meant. It can be called "Java" by its syntax. Also Scary Wombat, isn't System.out how Java interacts with standard streams?

Comment: I'm probably incorrect in thinking Java can run on systems where standard streams aren't availavbe, which is why I've become curious about how that works. Or can Java run on those kinds of systems?

Comment: For a web server for instance the sysout maybe redirected to a file

Comment: It is possible to have a no-op stream. e.g. `java > /dev/null`

Comment: But even when `System.out` is redirected (externally or by calling `System.setOut(...)`), the **variable** still exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the Java language specification which, in [section 7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3), says that

> Every compilation unit implicitly imports every public type name declared in the predefined package `java.lang`, as if the declaration `import java.lang.*;` appeared at the beginning of each compilation unit immediately after any package declaration. As a result, the names of all those types are available as simple names in every compilation unit.

there is also a [Java Compatibility Kit](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/JckAccess/) which any conforming implementation of Java must pass. Thus, anything which wants to call itself "Java" must include all the parts of Java, including `System.out`.

Comment: .... which is a good thing, because if a JVM implementor was allowed to tinker with the Java APIs, then portability goes out of the window (tied to a brick!).